# Is a grappling character considered to be distracted for the purposes of an attack by a second opponent?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, advantage-and-disadvantage

If a character is grappling a struggling opponent, and a second opponent attacks the character, would the DM rule that the distraction of dealing with the grappled opponent causes opponent number 2 to have Advantage on its attack?

I suppose it might depend on the nature of the Grapple. Merely grabbing an opponent by the wrist to impede his slingshot might leave you alert and ready to parry or dodge, but a more violent tussle, involving a grab with both arms would, I presume, leave you wide open for a whack from behind and thus at a Disadvantage versus a second opponent.

Even if you have followed up with a move to leave your grappled opponent Prone, I imagine that you are now kneeling, crouching or otherwise distorting your fighting stance in such a way (at least I cannot imagine that grappling a prone opponent can be done standing up) as to give a second opponent the Advantage.

I don't see anything in the Rules (I have Essentials Kit Rulebook) covering this.

The rules regarding grappled condition only speak of the relationship between grappler and victim. I am asking about the relationship between grappler and a third participant standing adjacent. Perhaps there is an applicable general rule somewhere that covers circumstances in which the character might conceivably be distracted (by which I mean Distracted as a Condition (in the manner of Blinded, Deafened etc.) which allows attack rolls with Advantage)?

Furthermore, one use of the Help action is to "distract the target" leading to the next attack roll against the target being made with advantage. So the target being distracted may be in and of itself the trigger for an Advantage roll. I am asking if being engrossed in a grapple might be considered a distraction for the purposes of Advantage. Seems to me the Rules might cover this somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

In D&D 5e the rules only do what they say they do. The [grappled condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled) does not give attackers advantage, it only reduces the grappled creature's speed to 0.

To give an ally advantage on an attack, you can use the [Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Help) action. You can use the Help action if you are grappling the enemy creature, but that isn't a prerequisite.

Comment: The rules regarding grappled condition only speak of the relationship between grappler and victim. I am asking about the relationship between grappler and a third participant standing adjacent. Perhaps there is an applicable general rule somewhere that covers circumstances in which the character might conceivably be distracted (by which I mean Distracted as a Condition (in the manner of Blinded, Deafened etc.) which allows attack rolls with Advantage)?

Comment: Furthermore, one use of the Help action is to "distract the target" leading to the next attack roll against the target being made with advantage. So the target being distracted may be in and of itself the trigger for an Advantage roll. I am asking if being engrossed in a grapple might be considered a distraction for the purposes of Advantage. Seems to me the Rules might cover this somewhere.

Comment: Being engaged in a grapple attack is not a distraction as per the rules as written.  I understand your logic, but the game rules are not written that way.  The third party would not have advantage.

Comment: Also you don't get a "free help action"  simply because the target fits the discription of distracted.

Comment: Again, rules only do what they say they do. The fact that nothing more is there to be found under the grappled condition description means that there is nothing more that happens.

Comment: Under the rules, the DM may decide that any situation merits advantage or disadvantage. Is your position that this situation doesn't merit advantage, or are you just observing that there's no explicit rule giving advantage in this case?

Comment: @Mark Wells Thank you for observing that the DM may under the rules determine that a situation merits advantage and disadvantage. Prompted by your comment, further internet searching showed me there is a rule in Chapter 7 of the Players Handbook to this effect. I feel that this is an important (the most important) part of a complete answer to my question (a meta rule beyond the simple Grapple rules which were silent on what I think is a fairly obvious point).

Comment: @PhilS The _most_ important piece is going to be an experience-based judgment call on whether giving advantage when attacking a Grappled creature is fair, makes the game interesting, improves verisimilitude, or otherwise helps achieve your gameplay goals. The meta rule from Chapter 7 isn't really necessary--you could always house-rule such a thing anyway.

Comment: @Mark Wells Both really. Invoking Rule 0 as the DM is fair, but not RAW or RAI for this. A grappled creature can't move out of the way as easily, but who/whatever is holding them is also in the way of an attack. Rather than apply both advantage and disadvantage, nullifying either from any source, the condition rightly (in my DM judgement) leaves both available. Personally, I treat it like the poisoned condition and add "while grappled, you suffer..." if I want an item or ability to highten the effect of the condition.